# $state.go() calls the controller of other state several times

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

Here are my states:

```
var states = angular.module("states", []);

states.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/landingPage");

  $stateProvider
    .state("landingPage", {
      url: "/landingPage",
      templateUrl: "../html/landing-page.html",
      controller: "landingCtrl"
  })
    .state("units",{
      url: "/units",
      templateUrl: "../html/units.html",
      controller: "unitsCtrl",
    })

});
```

Here are my controllers:

```
var controllers = angular.module("controllers", []);

  controllers.controller("landingCtrl", function($scope, $cordovaDialogs,$state) {

    $scope.getStarted = function () {

      $state.go("units");
    };

  });

  controllers.controller("unitsCtrl", function($scope){

    $scope.createUnits = function(){
     console.log("Hello");
    }();

  });
```

here is the associated html bit:

```
<button class="button button-assertive btn newbtn" ng-click="getStarted()">Let's Get Started</button>
```

Basically, the console logs "hello", specifically 4 times, when i get transferred to "units" state. Can anybody steer me into some general directions as why this happens? I haven't the foggiest.

Comment: Hello is not logged from the controller. It's looged from the createUnits function of the scope of the controller. WHere is that function used? What happens when you move the console.log() in the controller function itself?

Comment: that's a very legit question. I'm gonna take a look at that and will let you know. at this point the function is just a self invoking function in units controller of units state.

Comment: Appreciate the help. i just found that I had a custom element directive in the units page with the same controller as that of units page. that caused the controller to be invoked multiple times.